# Restrict the grid cell

Tags: qgis

I have donwloaded a Grid Cell from Internet, 0.5 x 0.5 degrees. It is a layer. On the other hand, I have the layer of the African continent. I would like to restrict the grid cell just to the borders of the African Continent, that is, I want to eliminate the part of the grid cell outside of the boundaries of the African continent.

I attach a picture of what I have.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbylocation) to select the grid-cells that do not overlap the continent. In the dialog window, for `Select features from`, use the grid layer. For `By comparing to the features from`, set the continent layer. Check the box next to `Disjoint`.

This will select all grid-cells that do not overlap the continent. Then delete the selected cells.

*Screenshot: red - polygon (representing continent), yellow: selection of cells to be deleted:*
[image]

To delete: Click on the grid-layer in the layer panel (on the left, no. 1 in the next screenshot), toggle editing (pen-icon, no. 2) and delete (recycle bin icon, no. 3):

[image]

Comment: Thank you Babel!

Comment: It works, but once I have done it, how can I delete the selected cells?

Comment: I updated the answer, see at the bottom how to delete

Comment: It works! Thank you!